Writing a Discord bot in Python hosted on Replit, getting an session error when I try to parse a command as a sentence
I'm writing a discord bot in python hosted on replit. Everything works fine as long as I parse commands as individual arguments. When I try to parse a command as a sentence, when I run my bot I get the error "session has been invalidated."
The syntax for a regular command is async def _cmd(ctx, arg1, arg2): or async def _cmd(ctx, *args): which work fine. The syntax for a command that parses the command text as a sentence is async def _cmd(ctx, *, arg):, that's what causes the error.
Here's the command I'm trying to run:
@bot.command(name="createmodule", description="Allows a teacher to create a new module in a class section he teaches")
async def _createmodule(ctx, *, args):
    response = "This command did not work."

    if ctx.author.id not in user_variables:
        response = "You are not logged in as a teacher."
    elif not user_variables[ctx.author.id]["teacherID"]:
        response = "You are not logged in as a teacher."
    else:
        idNameDesc = args.split('/')
        if len(idNameDesc) < 3:
            response = f"Please provide your response in the format [class section id]/[name]/[description]. Your entry: {args}"
        else:
            CreateModuleModeled = CreateModuleModel(ctx, idNameDesc[0], idNameDesc[1], nameAndDesc[2])
        
            CreateModule = CreateModuleModeled.response()
            response = CreateModule.responseString
    await ctx.send(response)

What could be causing the session error? How can I get around it? Is there an alternate way I can grab the command text as a sentence? Do I just need to tell my users to write_everything_with_underscores?
